# One-to-One Functions - A Deeper Understanding

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Definition of a one to one function - A function with domain $A$ is called a one-to-one function if no two elements of $A$ have the same image, that is, $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

I have a hard time understanding, especially when be testing, what $f(x)$ means. Is it another way to write $y$ in short hand? If so, why use it when explaining the $x$ value (the independent value)?

Comment: Also, all functions pass the vertical line test; however, not all functions are one to one due to the fact that they all do not pass the horizontal line test? Correct?

Comment: So the the notation for $f$ simply means that a function is to be applied to a value (or values) $x_{i}$. The image relation you have written above simply means that there does not exist to pre-image values that map the the SAME image value. If you want to call those image values $y$ then go ahead, that would be fine. Alternatively you could say that there only exists unique $y_{j}$'s arising from the function applied to unique $x_{k}$'s.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition, $f$ is a function. Any function has a domain, and an image. A function $f$ takes some element of the domain, and maps it to some element of the image. If, for example, the domain and image were both $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $f$ takes some real number and maps it to a real number), then we say $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. That is, $f$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

When we write $f(x)$, this means we are feeding the element $x$, from the domain, into the function $f$.

A function is one-to-one, if, as you say, no two distinct elements in the domain are mapped to the same element in the image.

An example of a function that is **not** one-to-one is $f(x)=x^2$. This is because, for any $a\neq 0$, $f(a) = f(-a) = a^2$. And clearly $a \neq -a$.

When we draw a graph such as $y = x^2$, what are we really doing here? We are plotting the function $f(x) = x^2$, where the $y-value$ for some point $x$ is given by $f(x)$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj3Aqov52TY Take a look here for a good understanding of the notation of functions.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f \colon A \to B$ is a rule which assigns to each element $a \in A$ an element $f(a) \in B$. So the notation $f(x)$ means the element in the codomain $B$ which is assigned to the element $x$ in the domain $A$.

The function $f$ is one-to-one if whenever $x_1 \neq x_2$ it is also true that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$. Loosely speaking, this means $f$ sends different things to different places.

One way to check if $f$ is one-to-one is to equate $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and then work (do algebra, etc.) to see if this means necessarily that $x_1 = x_2$.

Another way to do this is to graph the function $f$ and see if it passes the horizontal line test: If every horizontal line intersects the graph of $f$ in at most ine point (i.e. one or zero points), then $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: x[subset 1] = x[subset 2] means what exactly, loosely speaking?

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla $x_1 = x_2$ means that the two numbers are equal. If it's the subscripts here which are confusing, then you can make the same statement without them: $f$ is one-to-one means that whenever $f(a) = f(b)$, it is also true that $a=b$.